# How to show images through each card left and right arrow like a slider by using reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using react in an application.

I am trying to show cards (not by using bootstrap or other CSS Library). I using my own CSS to show Cards.
Now I want to show a left and Right Arrow on Each Card when each card 'll have some images related to it.

When user hover the mouse on each card and if there are some images then card 'll show left and right arrows and then user can click on left and right arrow to see more images.

I am using this example for this purpose and trying to implement though ReactJs.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow

Please see tried code below

```
------------------------------------------card.js-------------------------------
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Button from '../Button';
import Stats from '../Stats';
import { loadData } from '../../actions';
import './examplecard.css';

class ExampleCard extends Component {
  
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadData();       
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){       
    }     

    
    render() {                
          var slideIndex = 1;
            showDivs(slideIndex);

            function plusDivs(n) {
            showDivs(slideIndex += n);
            }
            
       

  function showDivs(/*n*/) {
            //var i;
            return
            (<div className="w3-content w3-display-container">
            {/* var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"); */}
            {/* if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} */}
            {/* var slideIndex = 1; */}
            {/* if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} */}
            {/* for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { */}
               {/*  x[i].style.display = "none";   */}
               <img className="mySlides imageHide" src="img_snowtops.jpg"  />
               <img className="mySlides imageHide" src="img_lights.jpg"  />
               <img className="mySlides imageHide" src="img_mountains.jpg" />
               <img className="mySlides imageHide" src="img_forest.jpg" /> 
            {/* } */}
            {/* x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";   */}
            
             <img className="mySlides imageShow" src={"img_forest.jpg"} />
            
                                
            <button className="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left"  onClick={() => plusDivs(-1)}>&#10094;</button>
            <button className="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onClick={() =>plusDivs(1)}>&#10095;</button>
        </div>)
        }

        return (
                <div>                   
                <div className="row">
                <section className="">   
                    {data.map(image => (
                        <div
                            key={image.id}
                            className="c"
                        >
                            <Stats stats={imageStats[image.id]} />
                            <div className="cad">   
                            <showDivs />
                             <img className="none"
                                src={image.urls.small}
                                alt={image.user.username}
                            />                             
                                <span>Description</span>                                                                                                                                  
                                {/* <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
                                    <img class="mySlides" src="img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%" />
                                    <img class="mySlides" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" />
                                    <img class="mySlides" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" />
                                    <img class="mySlides" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%" />                      
                                    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
                                    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
                                </div> */}
                            </div>                                                     
                        </div>                      
                    ))}
                </section>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


-------------------------examplecard.css-----------------------------------

.c {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.c {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}


.row {margin: 0 -5px;}
 

cad {  
  padding: 6px; 
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;  
}


.w3-content,.w3-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.w3-content{max-width:980px}.w3-auto{max-width:1140px}

.w3-display-container{position:relative}.w3-tooltip .w3-text{display:none}.w3-tooltip:hover .w3-text{display:inline-block}
.w3-display-container:hover .w3-display-hover{display:block}.w3-display-container:hover span.w3-display-hover{display:inline-block}.w3-display-hover{display:none}

.mySlides {display:none;}
.w3-button{border:none;display:inline-block;padding:8px 16px;vertical-align:middle;overflow:hidden;text-decoration:none;color:inherit;background-color:inherit;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;white-space:nowrap}
.w3-button{-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none} 
.w3-button:disabled{cursor:not-allowed;opacity:0.3}.w3-disabled *,:disabled *{pointer-events:none}
.w3-button:first-child,.w3-dropdown-click:hover > .w3-button:first-child{background-color:#ccc;color:#000}

.w3-button,.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-click .w3-button{width:100%;text-align:left;padding:8px 16px}
.w3-button{white-space:normal}
.w3-button,.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile,.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-btn,.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-button{width:100%}
.w3-button:hover{color:#000!important;background-color:#ccc!important}


.w3-black,.w3-hover-black:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#000!important}

.w3-display-left{position:absolute;top:50%;left:0%;transform:translate(0%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(-0%,-50%)}
.w3-display-right{position:absolute;top:50%;right:0%;transform:translate(0%,-50%);-ms-transform:translate(0%,-50%)}

.imageHide
{
  width:'100%';display:'none';
}

.imageShow
{
  display:'block';
}
```

I am trying to implement the same code as in w3schools but found some issues.

What should I do to fix in code?

```
Application built with
{
  "react": "16.13.0", 
  "react-dom": "^16.13.0", 
  "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
  "redux": "^4.0.4"
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5"
}
```

I am facing these error message .

./src/components/Cards/ExampleCard.js
Line 43:17:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: src={"img_snowtops.jpg"} shuld be  src="path_to/img_snowtops.jpg"

Comment: Your component structure wrongly constructed. Please check React documentation.

Comment: Yes  Paveloosha seems like this. correct me if you can .   thanks
Stefan still error on this line <div className="w3-content w3-display-container">